# RSpec has_many through #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy> on after_save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Heres my relationship model

```
class Address < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :address_aliases, :inverse_of => :address, :foreign_key => :address_id
end
```

In spec I am building an address with address_aliases. In my after_save of address I have used address.address_aliases.pluck somewhere, and it does not give correct value.

```
address_aliases = FactoryGirl.build_list(:address_alias, 1, :alias_for_city => "TEST1")
address = FactoryGirl.build(:some_address, :company_id => "test_company", :address_aliases => address_aliases)
byebug
expect ...
address.save!
```

This is what I get on byebug. address.address_aliases has one element, but when I pluck it returns blank array.

```
(byebug) address.address_aliases
#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<AddressAlias id: nil, alias_for_city: "TEST1", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, address_id: nil>]>
(byebug) address.address_aliases.pluck(:alias_for_city)
[]
```

Comment: You save the address, but not the aliases. So pluck (correctly) doesn't find anything in the db.

Comment: Also try creating the other way around: address first, then feed this address to the aliases.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I cannot create address_aliases seperately because I dont have the address id yet. If I create address_alias after address it will work but I wont get address_alias in after_save of address anymore. Tried the other way around too... its still the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the aliases are not yet persisted and `pluck` does a database query (see when you inspect `address_aliases`, the record does not have an ID yet, it's on memory, it's not on the database yet).

Replace that `pluck` with `map(&:alias_for_city)` so it doesn't do a database query and uses the already loaded collection.